# Calculate the value of a derivative at the origin

Tags: derivatives

I have the following question in a course:

An example of the logistic function is defined by
$$\varphi(v)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}$$ 
whose limiting values are $0$ and $1$. Show that the derivative of $\varphi(v)$ with respect to $v$ is given by 
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\mathrm{d}v}=a\varphi(v)[1-\varphi(v)]$$
What is the value of this derivative at the origin?

The first part is solved, but I couldn't understand the second (What is the value of this derivative at the origin?).

Can anyone help me?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: $1 / 1 + \exp(-av) \neq 1/(1 + \exp(-av))$.

Comment: @EFK10003 Please edit your question as it is unclear what $\varphi(v)$ is equal to

Comment: @EFK10003 That's more like it

Comment: @EFK $a$ is a constant?

Comment: $\phi(0)=\frac12\implies \phi'(0)=a\frac12\frac12$.

Comment: Yes it is @BLAZE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your function $$\varphi(v)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}$$
is a function of only *one* variable (which is $v$), the value of the derivative at the origin is given by setting $v=0$ in your equation for $$\frac{\mathrm{d}\varphi}{\mathrm{d}v}=\frac{a}{1+e^{-av}}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}\right]=\frac{a}{1+e^{-a\cdot 0}}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+e^{-a\cdot 0}}\right]=\frac{a}{1+1}\left[1-\frac{1}{1+1}\right]=\frac{a}{4}$$

Comment: Okay thank you @BLAZE . Just one more question, we always set v to 0 or just in this case since the limiting values are 0 and 1 ?

Comment: @EFK Explain what you mean by _limiting_?

Comment: In the question, the author wrote that the logistic function whose limiting values are 0 and 1. My question is v set to 0 is related to limiting values?

Answer (score 0):

$$\varphi(v)=\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}\Longrightarrow$$

$$\frac{\partial\varphi(v)}{\partial v}=\frac{\partial}{\partial v}\left(\frac{1}{1+e^{-av}}\right)=\frac{a\cdot e^{av}}{\left(1+e^{av}\right)^2}$$

Now if $v=0$:

$$\varphi'(0)=\frac{a\cdot e^{a\cdot 0}}{\left(1+e^{a\cdot 0}\right)^2}=\frac{a\cdot e^{0}}{\left(1+e^{0}\right)^2}=\frac{a\cdot 1}{(1+1)^2}=\frac{a}{2^2}=\frac{a}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

The limiting values are the limits the function is approaching towards positive or negative infinity. Graph the function with any $\alpha$ and you will see the result.